# AVAudioPlayer does not audibly play, throws no errors, calls no delegate method

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

Encountering a very weird issue. I'm trying to use AVAudioPlayer to play a simple sound file from disk. I maintain a strong reference to it via a property so ARC doesn't kill it prematurely. As I said in the title, I get no sound, errors and no delegate methods are called--including didFinishPlaying (which I would expect). The only thing that seems to "happen" is I hear two quiet clicks...

Now this is the weird part...if I set a breakpoint just before [_player play], then step over, the audio plays fine!! This basically confirms to me that I have set things up correctly, and makes me think that something else is stepping on the shared AVAudioSession from another thread? I'm not sure. The total lack of delegate calls is very odd--it seems that *something* should be called whenever AVAudioPlayer finishes.

I am also using OpenEars for speech recognition, but I call suspendListening on it before attempting to play the audio. I have also tried disabling OpenEars entirely, to try and isolate it as a cause--but this had no effect, either. Very perplexing. Appreciate any help!

```
-(void)playAudioNoteWithPath:(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                  withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth
                        error:&error];

    if (error) {
        DLog(@"ERROR setting audio session category: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    if (!URL) {
        DLog(@"No file path!!");
    }

    _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL
                                                 error:&error];

    if (error) {
        DLog(@"ERROR initializing audio player: %@", [error debugDescription]);
    }

    _player.delegate = self;

    [_player prepareToPlay];

// Setting a breakpoint here will cause playback to succeed.
    if (![_player play]) {
        DLog(@"ERROR playing!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I seem to have found a fix, though I'm not sure why...since it's not that much code, I just moved it into the calling class. So the calling class now plays AudioNotes directly, instead of AudioNotes playing themselves. Now it works.